# Animação CSS Está Repetindo

Tags: css, animação

Tenho uma `img` em minha página que aplico uma animação ao abrir a página.

### Attr

```
&.fundo-menu{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: -500px;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 312px;
    animation-name: LogoDesce;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}
```

### KeyFrame

```
@keyframes LogoDesce{
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        top: -115px;
    }
}
```

### HTML

```
<header id="header">
    {!! Html::image('img/open-menu-mobile.png', 'Abrir Menu Mobile', ['class'=>'open-menu-mobile']) !!}
    {!! Html::image('img/fundo-menu.png', '', ['class'=>'fundo-menu']) !!}
    <a href="{!! URL::to('/') !!}">
       {!! Html::image('img/mobile.png', '', ['class'=>'logo-menu-mobile']) !!}
       {!! Html::image('img/logotipo.png', '', ['class'=>'logo-menu']) !!}
    </a>
</header>
```

### JS

```
// Ao Rolar a Página Diminui o Menu
if ($(window).width() < 1024) {
  var MenuHeaderBox = $(".fundo-menu, .logo-menu, .logo-menu-mobile");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
      MenuHeaderBox.addClass('scroll-in');
    } else {
      MenuHeaderBox.removeClass('scroll-in');
    }
  });
} else {
  var MenuHeaderBox = $("header#header, nav.menu, nav.menu > ul, nav.menu > ul > li");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 300) {
      MenuHeaderBox.addClass('menu-fixed-scroll');
      if (!$('nav.menu > ul > li.logo-scroll')[0])
        $('nav.menu > ul').prepend("<li class='logo-scroll'><a href='" + urlBase + "'><img src='" + urlBase + "/img/torcane-logo-mobile-scroll.png'></a>");

    } else {
      MenuHeaderBox.removeClass('menu-fixed-scroll');
      $('nav.menu > ul > li.logo-scroll').remove();
    }
  });
}
```

Está funcionando essa parte. A questão é que quando eu rolo a página para baixo eu aplico um **JS** que esconde o `header` da página. Essa imagem está dentro do `header`.

Quando eu rolo para cima a página é para remover a classe que esconde o `header` e mostrar tudo ao normal novamente. Mas o que acontece é que a animação da imagem se repete. E isso está irritando.

A imagem não fica aonde parou na animação. Preciso que a imagem fique no final da animação, no `100%` do `keyframes`.

Tem como corrigir ?

Comment: Não posso falar **Boa Tarde a Toldos ?**, @ErlonCharles

Comment: Apresentações, boas vindas, agradecimentos e coisas do tipo não são necessárias. Embora seja uma maneira educada e respeitosa de falar aqui elas podem ser deixadas de lado, ninguém vai te considerar mal educado por ir direto ao ponto. :D